# How to create mappings with a function?

Tags: vimrc, vimscript

I am trying to create a function in vim that is capable of creating mappings for me. This is so I don't have to type out very similar commands over and over in my vimrc.

Take these two mappings as examples...

```
onoremap <buffer> in( :<c-u>execute "normal! /(\r:noh\rvi("<cr>
onoremap <buffer> in[ :<c-u>execute "normal! /[\r:noh\rvi["<cr>
```

*(these are operator-pending mappings for in paren or square bracket)*

What the mappings do is not really important for the question, what I would like to know is if I can create a function to remove all the repetition. I would like it to look something like...

```
CreateNextIn('(')
CreateNextIn('[')
CreateNextIn('{')
```

which will create the `omap` for me.

Any help will be greatly appreciated `:D`

Comment: Build mapping as  a concatenation of things that don't change as static strings and the things that change as sub-expressions/variables and pass the whole thing to `:exe`... `:exe 'nnoremap <leader>' . mapkey . ' :echo "' . somevar . '"<cr>'`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Thanks to `@B Layer's` comment...

> Build mapping as a concatenation of things that don't change as static strings and the things that change as sub-expressions/variables and pass the whole thing to `:exe`... `:exe 'nnoremap <leader>' . mapkey . ' :echo "' . somevar . '"<cr>'`

I have been able to answer the question.

Here is the solution to the above problem...

```
function CreateNextIn(str)
  execute 'onoremap <buffer> in' . a:str . ' :<c-u>execute "normal! /' . a:str . '\r:noh\rvi' . a:str . '"<cr>'
endfunction
```

Comment: Example: https://github.com/benknoble/Dotfiles/blob/master/links/vim/plugin/punctuation_textobjects.vim

Comment: Good job. Have a vote. Feel free to copy my comment in or paraphrase it...then the answer will better stand on its own (comments can always be deleted, too).

Comment: Good point. I have added that now. Thanks again for the comment